# Laravel Parent is soft deleted and child still trying to show causing error?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 I am having trouble calling a Related model when the Parent model is Soft Deleted...

In my Controller I have this which gets a Campaign record....

```
$campaign = Campaign::find($id);
```

In my View for this controller method, I call a related model like this...

```
echo $campaign->user->profile->full_name;
```

`User` is related to `Camapign` and `Profile` is related to `User`

My problem is, if a user is `Soft Deleted`, when I call `echo $campaign->user->profile->full_name;`

I get...

```
ErrorException  
Trying to get property of non-object (View: app/views/campaign/mapView.blade.php)
```

What I would like to do is instead show an error message that this users campaign is disabled/deleted since the User is soft deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect if a user has been soft deleted and do something like showing a message or redirect the application

```
if ($campaign->user->trashed())
{
    //show error message or redirect the app with something like Session::flash('error', 'There was an error campaign is disabled ');

}
```